# Adding a column in pandas DataFrame calculated from existing column and API call

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Trying to add to my dataframe a column based on an existing column in the DataFrame and an API call, but getting an Error.

Here is my code:

```
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
geolocator = Nominatim()

# address is a String e.g. 'Berlin, Germany'
# addressdetails=True does the magic and gives you also the details

properties_no_na['latitude_zipcode'] = geolocator.geocode(properties_no_na['zip_code'] + ', NYC', addressdetails=True).latitude
properties_no_na['longitude_zipcode'] = geolocator.geocode(properties_no_na['zip_code'] + ', NYC', addressdetails=True).longitude
```

When I try to execute this, it works and prints the latitude:

```
print(geolocator.geocode("brooklyn, NYC", addressdetails=True).latitude)
```

How to apply this to all the rows of my dataframe?

PS: 
1) zip_code is a string representing the zip_code of the house, and all rows are filled, no NaNs. 
2) To install geopoy:

```
pip install geopy
```

Here is a small portion of my df:
[image]

Comment: did you try the apply option of a dataframe?
[link](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) this pass on every cell and applys a function

Comment: Please no code or data as screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know iiuc.
Did you try e.g. sth like

```
properties_no_na['latitude_zipcode'] = properties_no_na['neighborhood'].apply(lambda x: geolocator.geocode(x + ', NYC', addressdetails=True).latitude)
```